# Generic Webservice Architect for Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, web-services, architecture

We have a web service written in C# running on Window 2008. We have two applications that need to access the web service. One written in C# and the other is in Java. We want to develop an over-arching architecture so both can call on the web service without us having to write two separate interfaces.  Does anyone know the best approach for this?

Comment: What is the problem with SOAP and autogenerated proxies?

Comment: Actually I found out the web services uses WCF, which solves all the problems.  Thanks for the response! =)

Answer (score 0):

Answer : To use Window Communication Foundation WCF.